Assigning to rvalue (50:8) when trying to build NextJS project with i18n routing
When trying to build my NextJS project with i18n+next-intl localization, I run into this error an I am not sure how to resolve it:
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-middleware-loader.js?absolutePagePath=private-next-root-dir%2Fsrc%2Fmiddleware.ts&page=%2Fsrc%2Fmiddleware&rootDir=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cluca-%5CWebstormProjects%5Clucidevme&matchers=
W3sicmVnZXhwIjoiXig%2FOlxcLyhfbmV4dFxcL2RhdGFcXC9bXi9dezEsfSkpPyg%2FOlxcLygoPyFfbmV4dFxcLylbXi8uXXsxLH0pKSh8XFwuanNvbnxcXC8%2FaW5kZXh8XFwvP2luZGV4XFwuanNvbik%2FW1xcLyNcXD9dPyQiLCJvcmlnaW5hbFNvdXJjZSI6Ii8ifSx7InJlZ2V4cCI6Il4oPzpc
XC8oX25leHRcXC9kYXRhXFwvW14vXXsxLH0pKT8oPzpcXC8oKD8hX25leHRcXC8pW14vLl17MSx9KSkoPzpcXC8oZGV8ZW4pKSg%2FOlxcLygoPzpbXlxcLyNcXD9dKz8pKD86XFwvKD86W15cXC8jXFw%2FXSs%2FKSkqKSk%2FKC5qc29uKT9bXFwvI1xcP10%2FJCIsIm9yaWdpbmFsU291cmNlIjoiLy
hkZXxlbikvOnBhdGgqIn1d&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=eyJtYXRjaGVycyI6W3sicmVnZXhwIjoiXig%2FOlxcLyhfbmV4dFxcL2RhdGFcXC9bXi9dezEsfSkpPyg%2FOlxcLygoPyFfbmV4dFxcLylbXi8uXXsxLH0pKSh8XFwuanNvbnxcXC8%2FaW5kZXh8XFwvP2luZGV4XFwuanNvb
ik%2FW1xcLyNcXD9dPyQiLCJvcmlnaW5hbFNvdXJjZSI6Ii8ifSx7InJlZ2V4cCI6Il4oPzpcXC8oX25leHRcXC9kYXRhXFwvW14vXXsxLH0pKT8oPzpcXC8oKD8hX25leHRcXC8pW14vLl17MSx9KSkoPzpcXC8oZGV8ZW4pKSg%2FOlxcLygoPzpbXlxcLyNcXD9dKz8pKD86XFwvKD86W15cXC8jXFw%2FXSs%2FKSkqKSk%2FKC5qc29uKT9bXFwvI1xcP10%2FJCIsIm9yaWdpbmFsU291cmNlIjoiLyhkZXxlbikvOnBhdGgqIn1dfQ%3D%3D! + 18 modules
Assigning to rvalue (50:8)
|     if (process !== __webpack_require__.g.process) {
|         // prefer local process but global.process has correct "env"
|         "MISSING_ENV_VAR" = __webpack_require__.g.process.env;
|         __webpack_require__.g.process = process;
|     }
while analyzing module javascript/auto|C:\Users\luca-\WebstormProjects\lucidevme\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[20].oneOf[1].use[0]!C:\Users\luca-\WebstormProjects\lucidevme\node_modules\next\dist\esm\server\web\globals.js|middleware for concatenation

Before adding localization with these modules everything was able to build just fine and i setup everything like they suggested on their website.
I'm running next-intl version 3.20.0 and i18n version 0.15.1 with NextJs 14.2.5
Here are the important files to my setup
my next.config.js:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}
const createNextIntlPlugin = require('next-intl/plugin');
const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin();

const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const { webpack } = require("next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack");
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = withNextIntl({
  experimental: {
    missingSuspenseWithCSRBailout: false,
    turbo: {
      rules: {
        '*.svg': {
          loaders: ['@svgr/webpack', 'esbuild-loader'],
          as: '*.js',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
    config.plugins.push(
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'}`),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/node:/, (resource) => {
        resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, "");
      }),
    );
    config.externals = {
      'next-intl': 'commonjs next-intl'
    }

    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,async_hooks: false,
    }
    return config;
  },
});

src/i18n/request.js:
import {notFound} from 'next/navigation';
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
import {routing} from './routing';

export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => {
  // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
  if (!routing.locales.includes(locale as any)) notFound();

  return {
    messages: (await import(`../../messages/${locale}.json`)).default
  };
});

src/i18n/routing.js:
import {defineRouting} from 'next-intl/routing';
import {createSharedPathnamesNavigation} from 'next-intl/navigation';

export const routing = defineRouting({
  locales: ['en', 'de'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  pathnames: {
    '/': '/',
    '/projects': {
      en: '/projects',
      de: '/projekte'
    }
  }
});
export type Pathnames = keyof typeof routing.pathnames;
export type Locale = (typeof routing.locales)[number];
export const {Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter} =
  createSharedPathnamesNavigation(routing);

src/middleware.js:
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import {routing} from './i18n/routing';

export default createMiddleware(routing);

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(de|en)/:path*']
};

The webpage itself works totally fine and like expected when using npm run dev in my IDE.
Can anyone guide me into the right direction on how to resolve this problem?
